# Is it possible to have a fileset with multiple source directories?

Tags: ant

I have some ant logic that looks like this:

```
<copy todir="src_@{version}" flatten="true">
    <fileset dir="${generic-libs.source}\prolo">
        <include name="**/*.c"/> <!-- all .c files including subfolders -->
        <include name="**/*.h"/> <!-- all .h files including subfolders -->
        <exclude name="**/test/*.*" /> <!-- exclude test (sub)folders -->
        <exclude name="**/test*.*" /> <!-- exclude remaining test sources -->
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${generic-libs.source}\genlo">
        <include name="**/*.c"/>
        <include name="**/*.h"/>
        <exclude name="**/test/*.*" />
        <exclude name="**/test*.*" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${generic-libs.source}\ptclo">
        <include name="**/*.c"/>
        <include name="**/*.h"/>
        <exclude name="**/test/*.*" />
        <exclude name="**/test*.*" />
    </fileset>
    ...
</copy>
```

The ... has 10 more identical constructs.

The contents of the fileset tag are always the same, so I guess there has to be a way to shorten this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ant 1.9.4 introduced [multirootfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/multirootfileset.html) for that purpose :

> A new resourcecollection type  acts like a union of `<fileset>`s and `<dirset>`s that share the same configuration but have different base directories.

In your case something like :

```
<multirootfileset basedirs="${generic-libs.source}\prolo,${generic-libs.source}\genlo,${generic-libs.source}\ptclo">
 <include name="**/*.c"/>
 <include name="**/*.h"/>
 <exclude name="**/test/*.*"/>
 <exclude name="**/test*.*"/>
</multirootfileset>
```